# form submission with delay

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to submit form after 10 seconds with form value. I am not able to include setTimeout with submit function.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#FrmID').submit();
}, 10000);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var grp_id = $("#grp_id").val();
    var datastr = 'grp_id=' + grp_id;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'start_calculate.php',
      data: datastr,
      success: function() {
        //$("#msg").html("Student Successfully Added");
        //$("#msg").html("response");
      }

    });


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="FrmID" id="FrmID">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $grp_id; ?>" name="grp_id" />
  <button type="submit" name="done" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="submit">Done !</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you expecting `$("#FrmID").submit();` to execute the `$("#submit").click()` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function for submit, then call it after click on `success`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function submitForm() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#FrmID').submit();
    }, 10000);
  }

  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var grp_id = $("#grp_id").val();
    var datastr = 'grp_id=' + grp_id;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'start_calculate.php',
      data: datastr,
      success: function() {
        //$("#msg").html("Student Successfully Added");
        //$("#msg").html("response");
        submitForm();
      }

    });


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="FrmID" id="FrmID">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $grp_id; ?>" name="grp_id" />
  <button type="submit" name="done" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="submit">Done !</button>
</form>
```

**In Action:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function submitForm() {
    i = 1;
    setInterval(function() {
      console.log(i++);
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#FrmID').submit();
      alert("Student Successfully Added");
    }, 10000);
  }

  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitForm();

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="FrmID" id="FrmID">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $grp_id; ?>" name="grp_id" />
  <button type="submit" name="done" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="submit">Done !</button>
</form>
```

---

And if you want to submit form automatically without press any key to submit you can try this. You should move your code inside the `setTimeout` function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {

    $('#FrmID').submit(function() {
      var grp_id = $("#grp_id").val();
      var datastr = 'grp_id=' + grp_id;

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'start_calculate.php',
        data: datastr,
        success: function() {
          //$("#msg").html("Student Successfully Added");
          //$("#msg").html("response");
        }

      });
    });

  }, 10000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="FrmID" id="FrmID">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $grp_id; ?>" name="grp_id" />
  <button type="submit" name="done" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="submit">Done !</button>
</form>
```

Or you can try `delay()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#FrmID').delay(10000).submit(function() {
      var grp_id = $("#grp_id").val();
      var datastr = 'grp_id=' + grp_id;

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'start_calculate.php',
        data: datastr,
        success: function() {
          //$("#msg").html("Student Successfully Added");
          //$("#msg").html("response");
        }

      });
    });

});
```

Comment: Nothing happens even after 10 secs.

Comment: @meenal it should work, check console log , see if there is error.

Comment: Yup ! it works, it was a typo mistake in my submission form! Thanks
Can i use `form.submit();` instead of `onclick();` i mean to say auto submission?

Comment: @meenal But no, because after `form.submit();` form submit automatically and you can't make a delay for submit data, so you need to handle it by click then set delay for submit.

Comment: If you mean submit form automatically after 10 seconds without press any button, the answer is yes, you can. @meenal

Comment: Yeah, Exactly! i want to remove the click option. it should submit automatically

Comment: @meenal odd, double check to sure everything is right, also check with new update code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you've not bound the submit handler to the form. Instead, you're binding it to the `click` event of the submit button.

You need to bind the handler code to the `submit` event of the form instead:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#FrmID').submit();
}, 10000);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#FrmID").submit(function() {
    var grp_id = $("#grp_id").val();
    var datastr = 'grp_id=' + grp_id;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'start_calculate.php',
      data: datastr,
      success: function() {
        //$("#msg").html("Student Successfully Added");
        //$("#msg").html("response");
      }

    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="FrmID" id="FrmID">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $grp_id; ?>" name="grp_id" />
  <button type="submit" name="done" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="submit">Done !</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submit").click(function() {

   setTimeout(function() {
    var grp_id = $("#grp_id").val();
    var datastr = 'grp_id=' + grp_id;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'start_calculate.php',
      data: datastr,
      success: function() {
        //$("#msg").html("Student Successfully Added");
        //$("#msg").html("response");
      }

    });

   }, 10000);
  });

});
```

On click of submit just execute your code after delay.